# C# Create Record in another entity after saved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I have a model like, let's say `TemplateMaster`:

```
public int TemplateId { get; set; }
public string TemplateName { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
public DateTime FinishDateTime { get; set; }
public double DurationHours { get; set; }
```

And I also have the following model, `TemplateDetail`:

```
public DateTime TheDateTime { get; set; }
public string TheNumbers { get; set; }
```

The scenario is: if I add a new record into `TemplateMaster`, let's say:

```
TemplateName = "Test-A",
StartDateTime = "2022-11-01 08:00:00",
FinishDateTime = "2022-11-02 10:00:00",
DurationHours = 0.5
```

then I need my code to also automatically create records in `TemplateDetail` model, with the following data:

```
TheDateTime                        TheNumbers
-----------------------------------------------------
2022-11-01 08:00                   1
2022-11-01 08:30                   2
2022-11-01 09:00                   3
2022-11-01 09:30                   4
2022-11-01 10:00                   5
2022-11-02 08:00                   6
2022-11-02 08:30                   7
2022-11-02 09:00                   8
2022-11-02 09:30                   9
2022-11-02 10:00                   10
```

How can I achieve that? Does anyone have an idea for this case?
Really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What ORM / database are you using, what have you tried so far, what did you expect, what errors did you encounter, etc etc.. In other words: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @riffnl, thank you. I have no idea how to achieve that in C# logic. I am using SQL Server as the database. no error found, because I haven't write a code for that case.

Comment: Is the database data written in the TemplateDetail model?

Comment: yes, it is. @Lynn-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

According to your model, I created TemplateMaster table and TemplateDetail table. TemplateMaster gets data from model. I insert data into TemplateDetail table. The detailed steps are as follows:

1. An entity class that encapsulates the operation database.

   ```
    public class DBHelp
   {
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();//Responsible for connecting data cool object connection
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();//The object command responsible for executing SQL statements
    string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=student;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

    /// <summary>
    /// Connect to the database
    /// </summary>
    private void ConnectDataBase()
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString; //Specify the connection string
        if(connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection. Open();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The SQL statement to be executed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command"></param>
    public void ExecuteSQL(string commandString)
    {
        ConnectDataBase();//Connect to the database
        command.Connection = connection;//Specify the connection
        command.CommandText = commandString;//Specify the SQL command to be operated
        command. ExecuteNonQuery();
        CloseConnection();//Close the database connection

    }

    public SqlDataReader Execute(string commandString)
    {
        ConnectDataBase();//Connect to the database
        command.Connection = connection;//Specify the connection
        command.CommandText = commandString;//Specify the SQL command to be operated
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();//Execute the SQL statement and get the result set reader

        return reader;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Close the existing database connection
    /// </summary>
    private void CloseConnection()
    {
       connection. Close();
     }
    }
   ```
2. Create a Gener() method to simulate the generated data.

   ```
   TemplateMaster tm;
   DateTs dt;
   public void Gener()
    {
          tm = new TemplateMaster();
          tm.TemplateName = "Test-A";
          tm.StartDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2022-11-01 08:00:00");
          tm.FinishDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2022-11-02 10:00:00");
          tm.DurationHours = 0.5;      
    }
   ```
3. The Index method implements the function of inserting data. The Show method displays TemplateMaster data. The FinI() method inserts data into the TemplateDetail table.The Finshow() method displays the TemplateDetail table data on the front-end page.

   ```
     // GET: Home
      public ActionResult Index()
     {

         Insert();
         return View();
      }
      public ActionResult Show()
    {
         dt = new DateTs();
         string commandString1 = "select * from TemplateMaster";
         var reader = helper. Execute(commandString1);
         if (reader.HasRows) //HasRows is used to determine whether the result set contains this result
        {
          while (reader.Read())//The while loop is used when the number of loops is not fixed. Every time the Read function is executed, it automatically reads a line
          {
              DateTime start = reader. GetDateTime(1);
              DateTime end = reader. GetDateTime(2);
              dt.StartTime = start;
              dt.FinishTime = end;
              Buff.Start = start;
              Buff. Finish = end;

          }
      }

          return View(dt);
      }

      public ActionResult FinI()
     {

     // DateTs ts1 = new DateTs();
      DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(Buff.Start);
      DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(Buff.Finish);
      int iz = 1;
      for (DateTime time = start; time <= end; time = time.AddHours(0.5))
      {
          // Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"));
          string commandString2 = "insert into TemplateDetail values('{0}','{1}')";
          commandString2 = string.Format(commandString2, time, iz);

          helper.ExecuteSQL(commandString2);//Execute SQL statement
          iz++;

         }
             return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Finshow()
       {

          string commandString2 = "select * from TemplateDetail";
          var reader = helper. Execute(commandString2);
          List<ShowTd> sts = new List<ShowTd>();
          if (reader.HasRows) //HasRows is used to determine whether the result set contains this result
        {
          while (reader.Read())//The while loop is used when the number of loops is not fixed. Every time the Read function is executed, it automatically reads a line
            {
                  ShowTd st = new ShowTd();
                  st.Times = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetDateTime(0));
                  st.Numbers = reader.GetInt32(1);
                 sts.Add(st);
            }
           }

            return View(sts);
      }
   ```

front-end code:

```
   @using TestTime.Models

     @{
          Layout = null;
     }

       @if (@Model.Count > 0)
     {
         <table>
           <thead>
                  <tr><th>Times</th><th>Numbers</th>
          </thead>
       <tbody>
        @foreach (TestTime.Models.ShowTd p in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@p.Times</td>
                <td>@p.Numbers</td>
               
            </tr>
        }
         </tbody>
       </table>
     }
   else
 {
              <h2>no data</h2>
 }
```

3. achieve effect.

   [image]